# checkout page is keep loading and error in magento 2

Tags: magento2, checkout, error, loading

**1. Checkout page error:**

*user login after click the checkout*

```
 Exception #0 (Zend_Validate_Exception): Validate class not found from basename 'Magento\Framework\Validator\EmailAddress

0 /var/www/vhosts/mariposacoffeecompany.com/httpdocs/vendor/magento/module-quote/Model/Quote/Address/Validator.php(42): Zend_Validate::is('gokul@stallioni...', 'Magento\\Framewo...')
1 /var/www/vhosts/mariposacoffeecompany.com/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/Model/AbstractModel.php(707): Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\Validator->isValid(Object(Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\Interceptor))
2 /var/www/vhosts/mariposacoffeecompany.com/httpdocs/generated/code/Magento/Quote/Model/Quote/Address/Interceptor.php(1714): Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel->validateBeforeSave()
3 /var/www/vhosts/mariposacoffeecompany.com/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/Model/ResourceModel/Db/AbstractDb.php(405): Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\Interceptor->validateBeforeSave()
4 /var/www/vhosts/mariposacoffeecompany.com/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/Model/AbstractModel.php(647): Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb->save(Object(Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\Interceptor))
5 /var/www/vhosts/mariposacoffeecompany.com/httpdocs/generated/code/Magento/Quote/Model/Quote/Address/Interceptor.php(1675): Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel->save()
6 /var/www/vhosts/mariposacoffeecompany.com/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/Model/ResourceModel/Db/Collection/AbstractCollection.php(593): Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\Interceptor->save()
7 /var/www/vhosts/mariposacoffeecompany.com/httpdocs/vendor/magento/module-quote/Model/Quote/Relation.php(24): Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\Collection\AbstractCollection->save()
8 /var/www/vhosts/mariposacoffeecompany.com/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/Model/ResourceModel/Db/VersionControl/RelationComposite.php(48): Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Relation->processRelation(Object(Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Interceptor))
9 /var/www/vhosts/mariposacoffeecompany.com/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/Model/ResourceModel/Db/VersionControl/AbstractDb.php(57): Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\VersionControl\RelationComposite->processRelations(Object(Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Interceptor))
10 /var/www/vhosts/mariposacoffeecompany.com/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/Model/ResourceModel/Db/AbstractDb.php(418): Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\VersionControl\AbstractDb->processAfterSaves(Object(Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Interceptor))
11 /var/www/vhosts/mariposacoffeecompany.com/httpdocs/vendor/magento/module-quote/Model/ResourceModel/Quote.php(306): Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb->save(Object(Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Interceptor))
12 /var/www/vhosts/mariposacoffeecompany.com/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/Model/AbstractModel.php(647): Magento\Quote\Model\ResourceModel\Quote->save(Object(Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Interceptor))
13 /var/www/vhosts/mariposacoffeecompany.com/httpdocs/generated/code/Magento/Quote/Model/Quote/Interceptor.php(1740): Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel->save()
14 /var/www/vhosts/mariposacoffeecompany.com/httpdocs/vendor/mirasvit/module-rewards/src/Rewards/Model/Purchase.php(322): Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Interceptor->save()
15 /var/www/vhosts/mariposacoffeecompany.com/httpdocs/vendor/mirasvit/module-rewards/src/Rewards/Model/Purchase.php(256): Mirasvit\Rewards\Model\Purchase->refreshQuote(false)
16 /var/www/vhosts/mariposacoffeecompany.com/httpdocs/vendor/mirasvit/module-rewards/src/Rewards/Observer/Order.php(124): Mirasvit\Rewards\Model\Purchase->refreshPointsNumber(false)
17 /var/www/vhosts/mariposacoffeecompany.com/httpdocs/vendor/mirasvit/module-rewards/src/Rewards/Observer/OrderActionPredispatch.php(83): Mirasvit\Rewards\Observer\Order->refreshPoints(Object(Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Interceptor))
18 /var/www/vhosts/mariposacoffeecompany.com/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/Event/Invoker/InvokerDefault.php(72): Mirasvit\Rewards\Observer\OrderActionPredispatch->execute(Object(Magento\Framework\Event\Observer))
19 /var/www/vhosts/mariposacoffeecompany.com/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/Event/Invoker/InvokerDefault.php(60): Magento\Framework\Event\Invoker\InvokerDefault->_callObserverMethod(Object(Mirasvit\Rewards\Observer\OrderActionPredispatch), Object(Magento\Framework\Event\Observer))
20 /var/www/vhosts/mariposacoffeecompany.com/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/Event/Manager.php(66): Magento\Framework\Event\Invoker\InvokerDefault->dispatch(Array, Object(Magento\Framework\Event\Observer))
21 /var/www/vhosts/mariposacoffeecompany.com/httpdocs/generated/code/Magento/Framework/Event/Manager/Proxy.php(95): Magento\Framework\Event\Manager->dispatch('controller_acti...', Array)
22 /var/www/vhosts/mariposacoffeecompany.com/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/App/Action/Action.php(96): Magento\Framework\Event\Manager\Proxy->dispatch('controller_acti...', Array)
23 /var/www/vhosts/mariposacoffeecompany.com/httpdocs/vendor/magento/module-checkout/Controller/Onepage.php(161): Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
24 /var/www/vhosts/mariposacoffeecompany.com/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Checkout\Controller\Onepage->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
25 /var/www/vhosts/mariposacoffeecompany.com/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Checkout\Controller\Index\Index\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', Array)
26 /var/www/vhosts/mariposacoffeecompany.com/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Checkout\Controller\Index\Index\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
27 /var/www/vhosts/mariposacoffeecompany.com/httpdocs/generated/code/Magento/Checkout/Controller/Index/Index/Interceptor.php(39): Magento\Checkout\Controller\Index\Index\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, Array)
28 /var/www/vhosts/mariposacoffeecompany.com/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php(55): Magento\Checkout\Controller\Index\Index\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
29 /var/www/vhosts/mariposacoffeecompany.com/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
30 /var/www/vhosts/mariposacoffeecompany.com/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', Array)
31 /var/www/vhosts/mariposacoffeecompany.com/httpdocs/vendor/magento/module-store/App/FrontController/Plugin/RequestPreprocessor.php(94): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
32 /var/www/vhosts/mariposacoffeecompany.com/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(135): Magento\Store\App\FrontController\Plugin\RequestPreprocessor->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
33 /var/www/vhosts/mariposacoffeecompany.com/httpdocs/vendor/magento/module-page-cache/Model/App/FrontController/BuiltinPlugin.php(73): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
34 /var/www/vhosts/mariposacoffeecompany.com/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(135): Magento\PageCache\Model\App\FrontController\BuiltinPlugin->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
35 /var/www/vhosts/mariposacoffeecompany.com/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
36 /var/www/vhosts/mariposacoffeecompany.com/httpdocs/generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/FrontController/Interceptor.php(26): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, Array)
37 /var/www/vhosts/mariposacoffeecompany.com/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(135): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
38 /var/www/vhosts/mariposacoffeecompany.com/httpdocs/generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/Http/Interceptor.php(24): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()
39 /var/www/vhosts/mariposacoffeecompany.com/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(257): Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor->launch()
40 /var/www/vhosts/mariposacoffeecompany.com/httpdocs/index.php(39): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor))
41 {main}
```

**2.Checkout page is keep loading**

user without login

[image]

Comment: Try recompiling your code. `rm -rf generated/*` and `bin/magento setup:di:compile`.

Comment: @Zankar we tried re-indexing and static-content:deploy

Answer (score 1):

Hello I think some validation fails at address so can you check below file

```
vendor/magento/module-quote/Model/Quote/Address/Validator.php
```

Some validation fails when you add address fields..I think for email it has some problem.

Comment: without login also problem, loading

Comment: can you check error log

Comment: ok i check and update

Comment: it is a (PLESK problem) https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-2-x-Version-Upgrades/2-1-9-to-2-2-0-Checkout-not-possible-not-found-basename-Magento/td-p/76437